# Two Rewrite rule with same numbers of query strings

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have this two rules:

```
RewriteRule ^segment/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ segment.php?id=$1&project=$2 [L,QSA,NC]

RewriteRule ^segment/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ segment.php?id=$1&sub=$2 [L,QSA,NC]
```

But it seems that they are being interpreted in the same way. You can identify the query strings in the rule?

Comment: You can't do such thing: the original requested urls do not contain any hint which argument is which.

Comment: matching pattern `^segment/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$` is same so only first rule will be executed.